# Laptop to "Desktop" Conversion

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, laptop

I have an old laptop which I no longer have the charger for. I ordered a new charger for the same laptop series, but the plug is too large, and it is unlikely that I will find the same adapter (Acer is difficult with their proprietary plugs).

I have an idea to connect the power supply directly to the laptop. 15.2V is the battery voltage. The charger provides an output of 19V at 3.42A.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: I thought they all used 5.5mm/1.7mm plugs.

Comment: Check out universal laptop chargers, they come with plenty of most bizarre connectors. Perhaps you'll find your luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acer has weird, but not necessarily proprietary connectors. If you have an electronics shop nearby, your best bet is to bring the laptop there and try until you find a matching one.

Desoldering a connector on a mainboard is a semi-difficult thing, because these are usually connected to large copper planes, so you need a high-powered soldering iron with good temperature control.

It is definitely easier to change the connector on the power supply than on the mainboard, though.

Comment: To be fair, Acer uses JST connectors for their mainboard connection.

Comment: I could take it to a shop, but I have already purchased a charger for the same series of laptop but with a connector which is too large. The question is asking if it is possible to strip the connector, remove the battery from the laptop, and connect the positive and negative wires to where the battery connected to the laptop.

Comment: @Anton8000 - It is generally not recommended that you do as you propose. The charger input is normally run through the charger circuit. This circuit has behaviors related to the charger activity that could get the BIOS or other power management aspects of laptop confused and at the worst do bad things. The battery pack also performs the important function of stabilizing the voltage delivered to the internal laptop SMPS which is not at all equivalent to a few much smaller capacitors out on the end of two to three feet of cable.